# Can't send data using Parse Push

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, notifications, push

I'm trying to send a push notification to my own device using Parse Push. However, whenever I try to set a JSONObject to as data, my device won't receive anything. I have tried setMessage() and it works. Any idea what's wrong?

```
                ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
                pushQuery.whereEqualTo("username", "abc@zzz.com");

                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();

                JSONObject obj= null;
                try {
                    obj = new JSONObject("{\"channel\":\"nom_nom_CH@\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}");
                    obj.put("action","com.parse.starter.UPDATE_STATUS");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                push.setQuery(pushQuery);
                push.setData(obj);
                push.sendInBackground();
            }
```

And for receiver

```
@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String jsonData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");

    JSONObject jsonObject;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));
        String channel = jsonObject.getString("channel");
        Log.d("Channel", channel);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Intent i = new Intent(context, Activity_Invite_nom.class);

    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: is your receiver methods trigger or not?

Comment: @kishorejethava i can't trigger it if I don't get any notification at all

Comment: You can see notif status from Parse Data browser (GUI) click on `Push` tab and you can see list and its status

Comment: @kishorejethava yes it is shown in the Parse website, but I don't receive anything on my phone

Comment: if `ParseInstallation` class has Channel than add one line `push.setChannel("channelName");` and  add `Alert` Message in Your Json `obj.put("alert","Request from User");`

Comment: Is your receiver set up correctly? Are you able to receive any pushes even if you send directly from parse console? Posting your AndroidManifest and PushReceiver would help

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem with my code. It turns out that I only need to implement these two lines

```
                        data.put("alert", "" + fullname + " invited you to nom!");
                        data.put("action", Parse_Receiver.KEY_PUSH_CHANNEL);
```

Thanks for the help everyone